# How to set path to PDFkit (gem can't find wkhtmltopdf)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, pdfkit

I'm running Rails on Windows and installed wkhtmltopdf(path - C:\Users\User\local\bin). I'm trying to configure it using documentation - https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit#configuration. But it gives me errors about path.

I create pdfkit.rb file in initializers folder and wrote this:

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltopdf = "C:Users/User/local/bin"
  config.default_options = {
 :page_size => 'Legal',
 :print_media_type => true
 }
end
```

but it gives me error

```
    No wkhtmltopdf executable found at C:Users/User/local/bin
    >> Please install wkhtmltopdf - https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit/wiki/Installing-WKHTMLTOPDF
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a / after C:?

Comment: Also, I don't know if you need to specify a backslash \ as path separator on ruby under windows

Comment: When I wrote what you are saying goves me error `Permission denied - "C:/Users/User/local/bin" "--page-size" "Legal" "--print-media-type" "--quiet" "-" "-"`

Comment: Ok but this is definitely a more reasonable error than "executable not found".

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL, so what you suggest ? I installed it right ?

Comment: That is definitely installed correctly, however I don't know why it says "permission denied". Check if you don't need also yo specify the executable too in the path, like: `C:/Users/User/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe`

Comment: Yeah, it is working! Thanks. But my css is not applying to PDF? However I have code : ` <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>`

Comment: I don't know this, maybe you can do another question because I'm not a PDFKit expert, link the question here so I can read about the problem clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the whole executable path and put a slash **after** `C:`

The path should look like: `C:/Users/User/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe` consider also that you may use backslash \ instead of slash / in Windows